# How to find the distance of an light source where it arrives parallel on the optic lens?

Tags: optics, estimation, lenses, approximations

This question is related to the question:
"how-to-measure-the-strength-of-a-prescription-eyeglass-lens"
That was asked in the following link:
https://rb.gy/lgp99

Han-Kwang Nienhuys explained how to find the optical power of a positive lens:
For a positive lens:focus sunlight (for safety, preferably on dark, inflammable object such as a brick) and measure the distance in meters from the lens to the brick. The optical power of the lens in diopters is one divided by the focal length. In the case of a +2.50 dpt lens, the focal length will be 0.40 m."
And if you don't have sunny weather, you can use a household lamp (preferably a small LED spotlight) at a large distance, for example L=5
m. You'll need to add 1/L
to the power (in dpt) measurements. For the 2.50 dpt example and a lamp at 5 m, you'll find the focus at 0.43 m; the lens power is then P=1/0.43+1/5=2.5
dpt.

My question is:
what should be the minimum distance of the lamp/led source from the lens,where we can say,that the led rays arrive parallel to the lens so we can ignore the additional calculation(the 1/5M example)?Is there any formula that i can determine the proper distance according to the focal length or the diopter of the lens?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: As a practical matter, you can make almost perfectly parallel rays for free by pointing a pinhole in a dark box at the sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be the light source distance, $f$ the focal length of the lens and $x$ the distance from the focal point of the image of the light source.

$\dfrac 1 u +\dfrac {1}{f+x} =\dfrac 1f \Rightarrow u =f\left (1+\dfrac{f}{x}\right )$.

So decide on the tolerance $x$ and then work out the light source distance.

For example, suppose you know that the focal length of the lens, $f$, is actually $410\,\rm mm$.
If the object (light source) is a very long way then the image will be formed $410\,\rm mm$ from the lens.
Now suppose you decide that you are happy with the image distance to be within $2\,\rm mm$ of the focus which I have called distance $x$, ie $v=f+x = 412\,\rm mm$.
To produce the image at that position $u = 410\left (1+\dfrac{410}{2}\right )\approx 84 \,\rm m$.
So putting the light source $84 \,\rm m$ from the lens will produce an image within $2\,\rm mm$ of the focal length of the lens.
If you need greater precision, then the light must be moved further away.

Now if you only know the approximate focal length, say $40 \,\rm mm$ then the calculation is very little different $u = 400\left (1+\dfrac{400}{2}\right )\approx 80 \,\rm m$.

If you do the experiment beware the fact that the lens will suffer from a number of aberrations which will mean that locating the image position accurately might be difficult.

Comment: The problem is that i don't have the focal length,as this is what i am trying to measure at first place.So i can't use this formula.I am trying to figure out,what distance should i locates the light source(led)from the lens so the light rays will considered to be as "enough"parallel,in order to measure the focal length when i get the focused light on the wall.

Comment: @xchcui You do not need the exact focal length to get an **estimate** of the object distance.

Comment: Can you give an example using this formula?Lets say that the focal length is 0.40m(+2.5dpt).

Comment: Your answer is not clear.Besides the focal length distance,I don't understand where is the x distance and where is the u distance.I attached a photo to my question,may you mark on it,where is the x and u distance?

Comment: @xchcui I have added a numerical example to my answer.